# Identifying and finding a replacement audio signal transformer 50 ohm / 0.5 ohm

Tags: transformer, audio, signal

I am trying to identify and find a replacement for the attached transformer.  The green/white leads with the red center tap have a 50 ohm resistance.  The side without the center tap has a 0.5 ohm resistance.

Can anyone identify what this transformer would be used for?  I am thinking it is an audio signal transformer, but that is not the application it is used on currently.  It is currently in an analog signal processing application.

I also cannot find anything close to the 100x impedance ratio, so I am not sure if I have classified it correctly.

Thank you for your help,
Tom

[image: Audio Signal Transformer]

Comment: Schematic please

Comment: An ohmmeter can only be used to estimate the turns ratio if the wire size on the primary and secondary is the same. This is often not the case. Do you have a function generator? Disconnect the transformer, put a 1 kHz sine, 1 Vp-p into one side and see what you get on the other side.

Comment: Why are you trying to find a replacement if you don't know what it's used for and it seems to be testing as OK?

Comment: What leads you to believe it was originally intended as an audio signal transformer?  The physical appearance could be the same for other types.  Although you mention it's used in an analog signal processing application, is it connected to analog signals?

Comment: You need to use an AC signal to measure turns ratio.  A DC resistance measure will not give you this information.

Comment: My ignorance is showing here.  It seems I need a function generator to measure the turns ratio.  Will an LCR meter work?  The one I have generates a 1khz AC signal.